# Issue Reading from a file and using a 2D array to sort the data

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mapping

I'm making a province sorter, and the requirement is that I must leave the main class as is, and make a private class called Munge, i've been at this for hours and changed my code hundreds of times, basically it reads from a text file that looks like this

> Hamilton, Ontario 
>   Toronto, Ontario
>   Edmonton, Alberta
>   Red Deer, Alberta
>   St John's, Newfoundland

and needs to be output like this

> Alberta; Edmonton, Red Deer 
>   Ontario; Hamilton, Toronto 
>   Newfoundland; St John's

my main class is unchangeable and looks like this

```
public class Lab5 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(args.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java -jar lab5.jar infile outfile");
        System.exit(99);
    }

    Munge dataSorter = new Munge(args[0], args[1]);

    dataSorter.openFiles();
    dataSorter.readRecords();
    dataSorter.writeRecords();
    dataSorter.closeFiles();
    }
}
```

and the Munge class i've made looks like this

```
package lab5;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Munge
{

private String inFileName, outFileName;
private Scanner inFile;
private Formatter outFile;
private int line = 0;

private String[] data;

public Munge(String inFileName, String outFileName)
{
    this.inFileName = inFileName;
    this.outFileName = outFileName;

    data = new String[100];
}

public void openFiles()
{
    try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
            File file = new File("input.txt");
            SortedMap<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String newline = scanner.next();
            if (newline.contains(",")) {
            String[] parts = newline.split(",");
            String city = parts[0].trim();
            String province = parts[1].trim();
            List<String> cities = map.get(province);
            if (cities == null) {
                cities = new ArrayList<String>();
                map.put(province, cities);
            }
            if (!cities.contains(city)) {
                cities.add(city);
            }
            }   
        } 
            for (String province : map.keySet()) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(province).append(": ");
                List<String> cities = map.get(province);
                for (String city : cities) {
                    sb.append(city).append(", ");
                }
                sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
                String output = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(output);
            } 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(SecurityException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("You do not have access to this file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try
    {
        outFile = new Formatter(outFileName);  
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(SecurityException exception)
    {
        System.err.println("You do not have access to this file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void readRecords()
{
    while(inFile.hasNext())
    {
        data[line] = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data[line]);
        line++;
    }
}

public void writeRecords()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        String tokens[] = data[i].split(", ");
        Arrays.sort(tokens);

        for(int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++)
            outFile.format("%s\r\n", tokens[j]);
    }
}

public void closeFiles()
{
    if(inFile != null)
        inFile.close();

    if(outFile != null)
        outFile.close();
}
}
```

you'll have to excuse my brackets, there formatted correctly in netbeans but i had to move the bottom ones over to keep it in the codeblock

Comment: This sounded like homework so I added that tag.

Comment: You should ask a specific question based on a specific problem you are facing in your solution so far. You've written some code, but you don't give any indication of how it is not working. I suspect your code isn't working, but you haven't really asked any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think this is homework I'll avoid giving you a solution but give some hints of what to do.

When you have read a line it consists of City, Province. So the first thing you need to do is split the string into two parts. The second part is the province and the first is the city. You need to make a collection for each province and store the city in the correct province collection.

Once you have that you sort the names of the found provinces, and iterate through them. Sort the cities for the province and then output the province name and each city name.

Useful classes could be will be HashMap, TreeMap, List, Collections (has sort methods).

Hope that helps to get you further, otherwise try to be more specific where you are stuck.

Comment: Map<String,List<String>> result; // careful selection of Map and List types here will make life a cake walk.

result.put(province, cityNames.add(newName));

A regex group matcher will make parsing trivial. Tops number of lines of code to implement: 15